# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 publish app with Enitity Framework (Css and SQL Error)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have just written an app with a simple user login. Here are the steps I have done (I get 2 errors, Css doesn't get loaded and SQL Connection can not be etablished):

1. Developed the app & tested (it's using Entity Framework for database which works perfectly)

   Result:

   [image: This is how the App should look like]
2. Published the app in Visual Studio.
3. Zipped the app. Created a folder named x in inetpub (IIS WWWROOT) on the Windows Server.
4. Granted Write/Read Access for all Users
5. Converted the Folder to an Application.
6. Installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

   My Server Name is called : VPS-ZAP443076-1\EXPRESS

I succesfully connected via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to SQL Server.
So the connection string be like this in `web.config` :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" 
         connectionString="Server=VPS-ZAP443076-1\EXPRESS;Database=AppAccessContext;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and it is.

I then started the published web site, which looks now like this (full CSS missing) :

[image: This is how the App should not look like]

Some link element from source ( published app ) :

```
link href="/x/Content/assets/appAccess?v=wc99y7YtU422ki4yrXaIKYQEv-4cIc0lpElJdFjVPoI1" rel="stylesheet"  (wrong)
```

It should be:

```
link href="/Content/assets/appAccess/frontend.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

Here is my `bundle.config`:

[BundleConfig.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT8YD.png)

So, back to the SQL part, I submit the form in the published app, I get the following error:

[image: SqlException]

Here I translated it to English (short version):

> Provider: SQL Network Interfaces, Error: 52 -
>   Could not find a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.

I know that the error is "clear" but i dont know what else i can do. Its completely messed up.

Also i have tested every apppoolidentity, turned loadUserProfile on true and so on.. i am really frustrated. does anyone has an idea what is the problem?

Edit: I am googling now for 32 Hours without a fix, finding 90% indian videos or answers which doesnt help me.

Comment: noone able to help ?

Comment: I recommend you separate this into two separate questions. It's too confusing where the actual issues are.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle Config:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/assets/appAccess/frontend.css"));
```

Layout file:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")    
</head>
```

Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="conn" connectionString="Server=VPS-ZAP443076-1\EXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AppAccessContext;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveresultSets=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Changes from your code:

1. Added 'Integrated Security=true;' to Web.config for Windows
   authentication to SQL Server.
2. Referenced the bundle in the layout file.

Try this code. Hopefully this is self-explanatory and makes sense.